OPC UA client error connecting to unsecure server: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'serverCertificate')
I am writing an OPC UA client in .net core 8 using OPC Foundation library. Mi server is KepServerEX 6 and it has a endpoint at 192.168.21.75:49320 that allows unsecure connections (encryption is disabled). I have checked the endpoint with OPC Watch and works good. But my code in .net fails with the following error despite my endpoint accept unsecure connections:

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter
'serverCertificate')

I have read that the OPC Foundation library should handle authentication and server certificate verification transparently, so I am not able to find how to solve this problem.
This is my code:
var endpointUrl = "opc.tcp://192.168.21.75:49320";
var endpointDescription = new EndpointDescription
{
    EndpointUrl = endpointUrl
};

ApplicationInstance application = new ApplicationInstance
{
    ApplicationType = ApplicationType.Client,
    ConfigSectionName = "client"
};

bool appCert = await application.CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate(false, 0).ConfigureAwait(false);
if (!appCert)
{
    throw new Exception("Application instance certificate invalid!");
}

EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = EndpointConfiguration.Create(application.ApplicationConfiguration);
ConfiguredEndpoint endpoint = new ConfiguredEndpoint(null, endpointDescription, endpointConfiguration);

var userIdentity = new UserIdentity("netdot", "12345");

var session = await Session.Create(application.ApplicationConfiguration, endpoint, false, application.ApplicationName, 60000, userIdentity, null);
        

And in the other hand, in my client.Config.xml file I have set AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates to true.
I don't know where I am wrong, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
EDIT:
I have added MessageSecurityMode.None in this way:
var endpointDescription = new EndpointDescription
{
    EndpointUrl = endpointUrl,
    SecurityMode = MessageSecurityMode.None
};

Now the error was replaced by this one:

The chosen security policy is not supported by the client to connect
to the server

EDIT2:
I have added applicationConfiguration to endpointDescription, and the code has changed in this way:
var endpointUrl = "opc.tcp://192.168.21.75:49320";
ApplicationInstance application = new ApplicationInstance
{
    ApplicationName = "OPC UA Client",
    ApplicationType = ApplicationType.Client,
    ConfigSectionName = "client"
};

EndpointDescription endpointDescription = CoreClientUtils.SelectEndpoint(application.ApplicationConfiguration, endpointUrl, false);

EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = EndpointConfiguration.Create(application.ApplicationConfiguration);
ConfiguredEndpoint endpoint = new ConfiguredEndpoint(null, endpointDescription, endpointConfiguration);

var userIdentity = new UserIdentity("netdot", "12345");
            
var session = await Session.Create(application.ApplicationConfiguration, endpoint, false, application.ApplicationName, 60000, userIdentity, null);

A new is error is triggering:

Certificate is not trusted.

It seems that the client does not accept the server certificate, probably because it is self-signed. I tried installing the server certificate in my trusted root certification authorities certificate store, but it didn't solve the problem. The trouble goes on.

Do you have a full callstack and the exact code location, that causes this error?

The exception is triggered in Opc.Ua.Core.dll, in the class UaSCUaBinaryChannel.cs. The constructor of this class receives a x509Certificate and checks if this serverCertificate is null.

I have added MessageSecurityMode.None but a new exception is triggering: The chosen security policy is not supported by the client to connect to the server
